# Zend <dt> <dd> decorators: what do I lose by removing them

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

This question is specific to Zend_Form. Zend_Form adds standard decorators such as `<dd> <dt> <dl>`. What do I lose if I were to remove them? Are they used by Zend_Form itself for error reporting or any other reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are solely for structuring the output of your Zend Form elements in a definition list. Whether your form renders errors is controlled through the Error Decorator.

See this series of articles by Matthew Weier O'Phinney:

- [The simplest Zend Form Decorator](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/212-The-simplest-Zend_Form-decorator.html)
- [How to layer Decorators](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/213-From-the-inside-out-How-to-layer-decorators.html)
- [Rendering Zend Form Decorators individually](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/215-Rendering-Zend_Form-decorators-individually.html)
- [Creating composite elements](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/217-Creating-composite-elements.html)

and Rob Allen's Zend_Form Tutorial:

- http://akrabat.com/tutorial/simple-zend_form-example/

Comment: I'd add that they make your form render nicely even without CSS styling :) And also add semantic meaning: "this element in dd (definition) is for username (as is said in dt - definition term) and the whole form is a list of such definitions"

Answer (score 2):

1) It's simplest and maybe the best practice to change appearance of forms via CSS, not by markup (by writing your own decorators), at least, when you're not experienced-well programmer. 
By removing DdDt decorator, lots of possibilities of CSS, such as input fields/labels/error-lists positioning, coloring, indenting and so on are lost.
For example, to `<dt>` or `<dd>` you can add own class in form initialization, which later can be styled, satisfying your specific needs.

See code:

```
$comment = $this->createElement('textarea','comment',array(
    'label'=>'Post a comment',
    'required'=>true
))
  ->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper', 
    'label', 
    'Errors', 
    array(
       'HtmlTag', 
       array(
          'tag' => 'dd', 
          'class'=>'elevatedField'
       )
    ) 
 ))
;
```

Now in CSS stylesheet in `.elevatedField{}` rule you may define specific look for this textarea field.
Actually, this example is not for default DdDt decorator, but it's explaining well ways of utilizing `<dd>` tag. Almost the same is for default DdDt decorator.

Look here what can be achieved with only css:
http://robertbasic.com/blog/styling-the-default-zend_form-layout/
And it's not a limit.

2) Semantics of html markup is lost too, which almost have no meaning, at least for today.

Also, DdDt are not used by Zend_Form itself for error reporting - there is another standard decorator named 'Errors' for this needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
```

OR
`$element->clearDecorators();` and setting your own decorator;