# Change decoration of checkbox element

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'd like to change to rendering of the checkboxes. By default, it's this:

```
<dt><label>%name%</label></dt>
<dd>%element% %error %description%</dd>
```

I'd like to have the following (a bit like the multiCheckbox):

```
<dt>&nbsp;</dt>
<dd><label>%element% %name</label> %error% %description%</dd>
```

I override the `Zend_Form_Element::loadDefaultDecorators()` with 
`My_Form_Element_Checkbox::loadDefaultDecorators()` so this applies to all 
checkboxes in use.

I can't get this working. I tried to swap the order of some decorators, but 
esp. the `&nbsp;` inside the `<dt>` seems hard to fix. How can I achieve this?

BTW, by default the chain looks like this:

```
$this->addDecorator('ViewHelper')
     ->addDecorator('Errors')
     ->addDecorator('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description'))
     ->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd',
                                     'id'  => $this->getName() . '-element'))
     ->addDecorator('Label', array('tag' => 'dt'));
```

Comment: You could write a custom decorator for this. Please see list of articles I have given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870955/zend-dt-dd-decorators-what-do-i-lose-by-removing-them/3871060#3871060

Comment: The point is I'd like to keep the `<dt>/<dd>` structure. As far as I can see, the label can be rendered by Zend_Form_Decorator_Label, the input element by Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper, the description by Zend_Form_Decorator_Description and the errors by Zend_Form_Decorator_Errors. Therefore only another order of the decorators should be enough. But correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Take a look a Matthew's presentation *Leveraging Zend Framework Decorators*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prepend with an empty dt, like many decorator problems, it can be solved with a custom decorator like [AnyMarkup](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/62/anymarkup-decorator) which allow to insert arbitrary markup anywhere in your form.

Just replace your label with :

```
->addDecorator(
    'AnyMarkup', 
    array('markup' => '<dt>&nbsp;</dt>', 'placement' => 'prepend')
)
```

However, in order to put your element in your label, you have to write a custom decorator. Something like this (not tested) :

```
class My_Decorator extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract {     
    public function render($content) {
        return '<label>' . $content . $this->getElement()->getLabel() 
            . '</label>';
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this! Atm I had it solved by using two HtmlTag decorators (so no `&nbsp;` in the `<dt>`) and used the normal label decorator (so it became `<input><label>`). Your suggestions can solve both problems.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are wondering, this is what I came up with:

File App/Form/Element/Checkbox.php

```
<?php

class App_Form_Element_Checkbox extends Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox
{

 public function loadDefaultDecorators()
 {
  if ($this->loadDefaultDecoratorsIsDisabled())
  {
   return $this;
  }

  $this->addPrefixPath("App_Form_Decorator", "App/Form/Decorator", "decorator");

  $getId = create_function('$decorator',
          'return $decorator->getElement()->getId()
                                             . "-element";');
  $this->addDecorator('ViewHelper')
      ->addDecorator('Errors')
      ->addDecorator('Checkbox')
      ->addDecorator('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description', "placement" => "prepend"))
      ->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd', 'id' => array('callback' => $getId)))
      ->addDecorator('AnyMarkup', array('markup' => '<dt id="'.$this->getId().'-label">&nbsp;</dt>', 'placement' => 'prepend'));

  return $this;
 }
}
```

File App/Form/Decoratpr/Checkbox.php

```
<?php

class App_Form_Decorator_Checkbox extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{

 public function render($content)
 {
  return '<label for="'.$this->getElement()->getId().'">' . $content . ' ' . $this->getElement()->getLabel()
  . '</label>';
 }
}
```

File App/Form/Decorator/AnyMarkup.php

```
<?php

class App_Form_Decorator_AnyMarkup extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{

 public function render($content)
 {
  $placement = $this->getPlacement();
  $separator = $this->getSeparator();
  switch ($placement)
  {
   case self::PREPEND:
    return $this->_options['markup'] . $separator . $content;
   case self::APPEND:
   default:
    return $content . $separator . $this->_options['markup'];
  }
 }
}
```